# What's the right way to set "dynamic" PATH in bash? (for android sdk)

Tags: shell, software-installation, path

I have android sdk installed, and I want the binaries in `build-tools/android-VERSION` to be available in PATH, so I add few lines:

```
ANDROID_SDK=/Application/Binaries/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140321/sdk/
ANDROID_PATH=$ANDROID_SDK/tools:$ANDROID_SDK/platform-tools:$ANDROID_SDK/build-tools/android-4.4.2/
```

Here's the problem, I might update the SDK at any time, so `build-tools/android-4.4.2/` might change upon that. If so I would have to edit the file again and update the `android-version` part in $PATH

So I changed the profile to something like this,

```
ANDROID_SDK=/Application/Binaries/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140321/sdk/
ANDROID_PATH=$ANDROID_SDK/tools:$ANDROID_SDK/platform-tools
for x in $ANDROID_SDK/build-tools/android-*/; do
    export PATH=$PATH:$x
done
```

That looks dumb, any better way to write it?

Comment: @devnull not files, "paths"

Comment: @devnull okay added a trailing slash

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve here.  Are you trying to do something so as to avoid editing your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile`?

Comment: @devnull Yes exactly

Comment: @devnull Just elaborated the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ideal way is creating a soft link directory called `adt`, and re-creating it after SDK changes.

Thus, your `PATH` will stay the same.

Comment: This looks like the most reasonable one.

Answer (score 0):

```
PATH="$PATH:$(printf '%s:' $ANDROID_SDK/build-tools/android-[0-9.]*/)"
```

Should work.

```
cd ~ ; mkdir dir1 dir2 dir3
( PATH=$(printf %s: $HOME/dir[12])
echo "$PATH" )

/home/mikeserv/dir1:/home/mikeserv/dir2:

Another method:

PATH="$PATH:$( set -- `printf '%s\n' "$ANDROID_SDK"*/android[0-9.]*/ |
    sort -rV` ; [ -d "$1" ] && echo "$1" )"
```

That takes advantage of *`sort's -Version`* handling, which should ensure that the positional parameter *`"$1"`* is always set to the latest version of your Android SDK. For example:

#### WITHOUT SORT:

```
% printf %s\\n ~/dir[0-9]*
/home/mikeserv/dir1
/home/mikeserv/dir2
/home/mikeserv/dir23
/home/mikeserv/dir3
/home/mikeserv/dir45
```

#### WITH IT:

```
%  printf %s\\n ~/dir[0-9]* | sort -V
/home/mikeserv/dir1
/home/mikeserv/dir2
/home/mikeserv/dir3
/home/mikeserv/dir23
/home/mikeserv/dir45
```

#### AND REVERSED:

```
% printf %s\\n ~/dir[0-9]* | sort -rV
/home/mikeserv/dir45
/home/mikeserv/dir23
/home/mikeserv/dir3
/home/mikeserv/dir2
/home/mikeserv/dir1
```

Answer (score 0):

In this approach, on two occasions the output of `ls`, sorted on time and for directories only (`-td`), is piped to the `head` command which then selects the first line. The result is that the most recent version of both `adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-*/sdk` and of `build-tools/android-*/` should be used for the modification of the PATH environment variable.

```
ANDROID_SDK=$( ls -td /Application/Binaries/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-*/sdk/ | head -n 1 )
if ! [ -z $ANDROID_SDK ] ; then
    ANDROID_PATH=$ANDROID_SDK/tools:$ANDROID_SDK/platform-tools
    ANDROID_BUILDTOOLS=$( ls -td $ANDROID_SDK/build-tools/android-*/ | head -n 1 )
    if ! [ -z $ANDROID_BUILDTOOLS ] ; then
        echo "Adding $ANDROID_BUILDTOOLS to PATH"
        export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_BUILDTOOLS
    else
        echo "Couldn't find build tools"
    fi
else
    echo "Couldn't find SDK"
fi
```