# How to dynamically change path for different environment?

Tags: bash, path

I have different versions of CUDA installed in `/usr/local/cuda-...` and
I need some way to select the right version for different projects.

I tried

```
export CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda-10.0
export PATH=\$CUDA_HOME/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=\$CUDA_HOME/lib64${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}
```

but it seems like variables in PATH don't get expanded.

My currently best idea is something like this:

```
BASEPATH=$PATH:$HOME/installed/pycharm-community-2020.2/bin
LIBBASEPATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

function env100() {
    CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda-10.0
    setpaths
}

function env101() {
    CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda-10.1
    setpaths
}

function setpaths() {
    export PATH=$BASEPATH:$CUDA_HOME/bin
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LIBBASEPATH:$CUDA_HOME/lib64
}
```

but I cannot imagine that this is the easiest way to do what I want. And I haven't used it long enough to know all the weird ways in which it will explode, either. (Edit: First thing to explode: Python virtualenvs.)

Related:
I am trying to do something similar to this question: [What's the right way to set "dynamic" PATH in bash? (for android sdk)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122225/whats-the-right-way-to-set-dynamic-path-in-bash-for-android-sdk)

So, let's hear your recommendations!

Answer (score 0):

Without more information about what you're trying to do it's hard to recommend something:

- Path expansion is done like this: `PATH=$PATH:$CUDA_HOME/bin:/foo/otherpath`
- You could create more users, setup the specific PATH for each user environment in `.bashrc` (if using bash) and `export` it. To switch between users run `su username` run `exit` to switch back. Run `whoami` for orientation. Run `echo $SHLVL` to see in which shell level you're in. In the first shell the `SHLVL` counter var starts with 1, each `su` adds one to it, `exit` subtracts one from it.
- Setting the `PATH` var in a shell script without `export`ing it. This will only change the `PATH` for the subshell the script is running in.

test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/home/foo
echo $PATH
```

run `./test.sh;echo $PATH`

- If you're compiling code using `make`, you could add/change the path to a [Makefile](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11530/adding-directory-to-path-through-makefile)